# Existence of Point of Inflection

Tags: calculus

Does all the function have a point of inflection? And what is the importance of point of inflection in the real-world scenario?

Comment: No.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point

Comment: I think that a differentiable function does not have a point of inflection $ \iff $ it is either concave or convex.